# Enforcing Coding standards for Github repositories across team

Tags: java, github, coding-style, standards, pre-commit-hook

We are using Github as VCS for our Java project. I am figuring out ways to enforce coding standards before pushing to remote repositories for members of my team.

```
On researching, I came across this github pre-commit web hooks.
```

But after research found out that it isn't possible to maintain the scripts centrally within the repository. So I have few questions at this point.

1. Is pre-commit hooks a right way to enforce coding standards across team ? (I know it definitely isn't but wanna hear it from the experienced guys)
2. If enforcing coding standards is feasible only at the Continous integration stage then with what tools do I achieve that to enforce Java coding standards for my projects across the team ?

My question is something similar on the lines of this one '

[How to enforce Coding Standard for the repository located in GIthub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955088/how-to-enforce-coding-standard-for-the-repository-located-in-github)

Answer (score 1):

What kind of coding standards do you want to enforce?

If you want to prevent possible problems that can be found with static code analysis with tools like *PMD* and *checkstyle*, you can integrate these checks within your continuous integration server and make the build fail if specific checks fail.

[edit] sorry, my answer is very similar to the one of the other question - in which point does your question differ from the other one?

Comment: I wanna enforce that the commit is bug-free i.e FindBugs validated & also complies checkstyle

Comment: Is it not possible to enforce these at the commit level ?

Comment: You can use a `post-receive hook` if you use one git server as *the central server* so that you only have to ensure the hook is beeing set on one side and not on all clients.